# Synergy Client how to set password

Tags: linux, synergy

I have a windows Synergy 1.5.1 server with a password set.
If I turn off the password on the server I can connect to it with my Debian client with this command:

```
synergyc -f -d INFO 192.168.1.115
```

But when the password is enabled on the server, I can't connect; Probably due to the fact the password is not set on the client.

```
synergyc -h
```

Reveals no commandline options to set the password. I am guessing I need to create a synergy.conf on the client. But I cant find any documentation on writing a synergy.conf for the client. ( Although, there is plenty of information on configuring the server.)

There appears to be no documented way to specify the password to the linux client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoudl be able to give the password when starting the client as follows:

```
synergyc --crypto-pass <hashed-password> <server-host-name>
```

But, `<hashed-password>` should be an `md5sum` of the actual password, use that command to achieve this:

```
echo -n <password-in-clear-text> | md5sum
```

Comment: I don't see `crypto-pass` as an option in the help listing of synergyc. I noticed that there is a `--enable-crypto` option but that isn't listed either, I just found it on the net (to enable the use of SSL). Does this imply there's a way to password protect the synergy server?

Comment: It appears that `crypto-pass` is deprecated, and now we only have `--enable-crypto`.